# Scroll to specific section in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I scroll to specific section in flutter ?

I have webpage with

- `header`
- `main`
- `footer`

When i click `footer`, I want to go to the `footer` section.

I just know we have to use `ScrollController` but ran out of resources to figure out solution, seems easy but couldn't find a solution.

Headsup, It is not just simple `ListView`, so `ListView's` approach to go to specific index wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create `Global Key`

   ```
    GlobalKey _containerKey = GlobalKey();
   ```
2. Assign key to the section to scroll to:

   ```
   Container(
     key: _containerKey,
     // other footer widgets
   ),
   ```
3. Go to the section on `onPressed` using `_containerKey.currentContext`:

   ```
   onPressed: () {
     Scrollable.ensureVisible(
       _containerKey.currentContext!,
       duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
       curve: Curves.easeInOut,
     );
   },
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Scrollable.ensureVisible(contextToBeVisible)`

Just pass the context of the e.g. footer and the scrolling will happen if e.g. combined with an onTap event:

```
onTap: () => Scrollable.ensureVisible(contextToBeVisible)
```

Official docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Scrollable/ensureVisible.html

And there are numerous examples here on SO.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know , where to lookout for. I appreciate.